# SharePoint Online: Display form (Newform.aspx/Upload.aspx) instead of Pop up dialog for uploading documents in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload, modal-dialog, popup

My current environment is SharePoint Online.

I want to customize (Newform.aspx/Upload.aspx) for a document library and want to show user a customized form instead of popup dialog after uploading document. How to customize this form? 
Just FYI
**Launch in popup dialog is set to NO**.
[image: Upload document]

I don't want to show a pop up screen [image: Popup dialog], instead want to show a customized form (Like newform.aspx on SharePoint lists/editform.aspx on document library)

Is this possible? Any suggestions please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apart from opening the form in the same window (no popup), could you brief what form customization are you looking for? Are they show/hide fields or form/fields layout related?

Comment: I want to add some scripts in the place where they add metadata to the document.

Answer (score 0):

If adding some scripts (example javascript) are required, you could add a content editor web part CEWP on the Default Edit Form which is located under library settings ribbon as show below. Add your scripts in CEWP. When a document is uploaded, the next dialog that comes up is a Default Edit Form to add the metadata.

[image]

To open the upload document dialog in the same window (no dialog), seems not possible unless someone put some light on it. The first dialog https://site_url/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=list_guid&RootFolder=&IsDlg=0 that uploads the  document can be open in a new tab window but then it fails to proceed further to the screen where we add the metadata.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to hide fields is by editing the content type in the library setting, then click on the field names you don't want and choose hidden.
If you need to remove modified/ created by at the bottom you need to format the form using infopath.

Comment: Mirlis, I was asking on how to show a customized form like (editform.aspx for document library) instead of popup dialog after uploading document (1st image).